# undecidable problems in Euclidean geometry

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, axioms

What is (are) the most "elementary" question(s) one could ask in Euclidean geometry with all its postulates/axioms including the "5th" that is (are) known to be undecidable. The "5th" is undecidable by the rest but Godel says even if we include it there will be something else. What would be the next simplest question one could ask in the axiom system with the 5th that cannot decided? I am looking for questions that are simple, intuitive, visualizable so I could show it to a 10 years old as an example.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms

Comment: "The "5th" is undecidable by the rest but Godel says even if we include it there will be something else." That's not true. Godel's theorem only applies to *certain kinds of* formal systems, and Euclidean geometry isn't such a system; indeed, [Tarski's presentation of Euclidean geometry is complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms).

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks, but now I am in a pickle... anyhow this question is just an example of the "6th" axiom: "of which one knows nothing one should keep quiet..."